# Passing input data from one form to a label in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have some labels on a form whose purpose is to hold values from the user input of another form, therefore, I need to set the label text programatically instead of with the properties window.  I have done this but the problem is that the data does not seem to be passing to the other form.  I tried running debug but the solution locks up on me and I have to shut it down from the task manager.  I had a breakpoint set on the method that opens the second form. My thinking was that as the program stepped through the method I could see if the properties were being filled with the correct info. Unfortunately, instead of stepping through the method, it just opens up the form and locks up

I am hoping that maybe someone could take a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong.

After the user inputs all of the data, he/she clicks a button which saves it to the database and displays a message asking the user to click another button to go to another form.  This part works fine.  Here is the event handler code for that action:

```
private void btnEnterNutritionInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call methods from NutritionBOL class to input calculated 
    //data into textboxes
    this.txtRMR.Text = Convert.ToString(busObject.GetRMRdata(
        busObject.BodyWeight));
    this.txtDailyActivityBurn.Text = Convert.ToString(
        busObject.GetDailyActivityBurnData(
        busObject.RestingMetabolicRate));
    this.txtEnergyAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(
        busObject.GetEnergyAmount(
        busObject.RestingMetabolicRate, busObject.DailyActivityBurn));
    this.txtYourNutritionLevel.Text = busObject.GetNutritionLevel(
        busObject.DailyEnergyAmount);

    //convert text box data and assign to variables
    busObject.BodyFatStart = double.Parse(this.txtBodyFatStart.Text);
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase1 = double.Parse(this.txtBodyFatEndOfPhase1.Text);
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase2 = double.Parse(this.txtbodyFatEndOfPhase2.Text);
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase3 =  double.Parse(this.txtbodyFatEndOfPhase3.Text);             
    busObject.BodyWeight = double.Parse(this.txtBodyWeight.Text);
    busObject.RestingMetabolicRate = double.Parse(this.txtRMR.Text);
    busObject.DailyActivityBurn = double.Parse(this.txtDailyActivityBurn.Text);
    busObject.DailyEnergyAmount = double.Parse(this.txtEnergyAmount.Text);
    busObject.BodyFatStartNotes = this.txtStartNotes.Text;
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase1Notes = this.txtBodyFatEndOfPhase1Notes.Text;
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase2Notes = this.txtBodyFatEndOfPhase2Notes.Text;
    busObject.BodyFatEndOfPhase3Notes = this.txtBodyFatEndOfPhase3Notes.Text;
    busObject.NutritionLevel = this.txtYourNutritionLevel.Text;  


    //call method to save input data
    busObject.SaveData();

    //set visibility to true
    txtRMR.Visible = true;
    txtDailyActivityBurn.Visible = true;
    txtEnergyAmount.Visible = true;
    txtYourNutritionLevel.Visible = true;
    lblYourNutritionLevel.Visible = true;
}
```

Once that is finished, the user clicks the button to go to the other form.  At this point, the label data is supposed to be passed to the other form.  The other form opens, but the label data isn't filled:  Here is the event handler for that button click:

```
private void btnMeasurementData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //assign text boxes to properties 
    this.BodyFatB4 = this.txtBodyFatStart.Text;
    this.BodyWeightB4 = this.txtBodyWeight.Text;
    this.BodyFatAfter = this.txtBodyFatEndOfPhase1.Text;
    this.BodyWeightAfter = this.txtBodyWeight.Text;

    //instantiate an object from the MeasurementsBOL to pass data
    MeasurementsForm measurementsForm = new MeasurementsForm();
    measurementsForm.BodyFatB4 = this.BodyFatB4;
    measurementsForm.BodyWeightB4 = this.BodyWeightB4;
    measurementsForm.BodyFatAfter = this.BodyFatAfter;
    measurementsForm.BodyWeightAfter = this.BodyWeightAfter;

    //StartDate data is just being passed through to the 
    //MeasurementsForm from the FitnessTest form
    measurementsForm.StartDate = this.StartDate;            

    this.Hide();

    //method call to open MeasurementsForm
    busObject.GoToMeasurementsForm(this.StartDate, this.BodyFatB4,
        this.BodyWeightB4, this.BodyFatAfter, this.BodyWeightAfter);
}
```

Here is the code for the method call to open the MeasurementsForm:

```
public void GoToMeasurementsForm(string startDate, string bodyFatB4,
    string bodyWeightB4, string bodyFatAfter, string bodyWeightAfter)
{
    MeasurementsForm f2;
    //logic to decide what to do if an instance is not already instanitated
    if (Application.OpenForms["MeasurementsForm"] == null)
    {
        f2 = new MeasurementsForm();
        f2.StartDate = startDate;
        f2.BodyFatB4 = bodyFatB4;
        f2.BodyWeightB4 = bodyWeightB4;
        f2.BodyFatAfter = bodyFatAfter;
        f2.BodyWeightAfter = bodyWeightAfter;
        f2.Name = "MeasurementsForm";
    }
    //logic to decide what to do if an instance is not already instantiated
    else
    {
        f2 = Application.OpenForms["MeasurementsForm"] as MeasurementsForm;
        f2.StartDate = startDate;
        f2.BodyFatB4 = bodyFatB4;
        f2.BodyWeightB4 = bodyWeightB4;
        f2.BodyFatAfter = bodyFatAfter;
        f2.BodyWeightAfter = bodyWeightAfter;
    }
        f2.Show();
}
```

This is the code for the form that opens when the button is clicked:

```
public partial class MeasurementsForm : Form
{
    //declare variables
    string bodyFatB4 = "",
           bodyWeightB4 = "",
           bodyFatAfter = "",
           bodyWeightAfter = "",
           startDate = "";

    //instantiate object from MeasurementsBOL class
    MeasurementsBOL busObject = new MeasurementsBOL();        

    //default constructor
    public MeasurementsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        busObject.InitializeConnection();
    }

    //properties for variables
    public string BodyFatB4
    {
        get { return bodyFatB4; }
        set { bodyFatB4 = value; }
    }

    public string BodyWeightB4
    {
        get { return bodyWeightB4; }
        set { bodyWeightB4 = value; }
    }

    public string BodyFatAfter
    {
        get { return bodyFatAfter; }
        set { bodyFatAfter = value; }
    }

    public string BodyWeightAfter
    {
        get { return bodyWeightAfter; }
        set { bodyWeightAfter = value; }
    }

    public string StartDate
    {
        get { return startDate; }
        set { startDate = value; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //pass text data from nutrition form to labels
        this.lblBodyFatB4FromNutrition.Text = this.BodyFatB4;
        this.lblWeightB4FromNutrition.Text = this.BodyWeightB4;
        this.lblBodyFatAfterFromNutrition.Text = this.BodyFatAfter;
        this.lblWeightAfterFromNutrition.Text = this.BodyWeightAfter;
    }

    //event handler for B4 input data
    private void btnEnterMeasurementsB4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //convert input data and assign to variables
        busObject.BodyFatB4 = double.Parse(lblBodyFatB4FromNutrition.Text);
        busObject.BodyWeightB4 = double.Parse(lblWeightB4FromNutrition.Text);
        busObject.ChestMeasurementB4 = double.Parse(txtChestB4.Text);
        busObject.WaistMeasurementB4 = double.Parse(txtWaistB4.Text);
        busObject.HipsMeasurementB4 = double.Parse(txtHipsB4.Text);
        busObject.RightThighB4 = double.Parse(txtRightThighB4.Text);
        busObject.LeftThighB4 = double.Parse(txtLeftThighB4.Text);
        busObject.RightArmB4 = double.Parse(txtRightArmB4.Text);
        busObject.LeftArmB4 = double.Parse(txtLeftArmB4.Text);

        //call method to save input data
        busObject.SaveB4Data();

        //clear text boxes of data
        this.txtChestB4.Clear();
        this.txtWaistB4.Clear();
        this.txtHipsB4.Clear();
        this.txtRightThighB4.Clear();
        this.txtLeftThighB4.Clear();
        this.txtRightArmB4.Clear();
        this.txtLeftArmB4.Clear();

        //close form
        this.Close();            
    }

    //event handler for after input data 
    private void btnEnterMeasurementsAfter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //convert input data and assign to variables      
        busObject.BodyFatAfter = double.Parse(lblBodyFatAfterFromNutrition.Text);
        busObject.BodyWeightAfter = double.Parse(lblWeightAfterFromNutrition.Text);
        busObject.ChestMeasurementAfter = double.Parse(txtChestAfter.Text);
        busObject.WaistMeasurementAfter = double.Parse(txtWaistAfter.Text);
        busObject.HipMeasurementAfter = double.Parse(txtHipsAfter.Text);
        busObject.RightThighAfter = double.Parse(txtRightThighAfter.Text);
        busObject.LeftThighAfter = double.Parse(txtLeftThighAfter.Text);
        busObject.RightArmAfter = double.Parse(txtRightArmAfter.Text);
        busObject.LeftArmAfter = double.Parse(txtLeftArmAfter.Text);

        //call method to save input data
        busObject.SaveAfterData();

        //clear text boxes of data
        this.txtChestAfter.Clear();
        this.txtWaistAfter.Clear();
        this.txtHipsAfter.Clear();
        this.txtRightThighAfter.Clear();
        this.txtLeftThighAfter.Clear();
        this.txtRightArmAfter.Clear();
        this.txtLeftArmAfter.Clear();

        //close form
        this.Close();
    }

    //event handler to open schedule form and hide this form
    private void btnClickForSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        busObject.BackToMainSchedule(this.StartDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeBlend - I had my breakpoint set on the method that opens the second form.  My thinking was that as the program stepped through the method I could see if the properties were being filled with the correct info.  Unfortunately, instead of stepping through the method, it just opens up the form and locks up

Comment: if it locks up then print out some lines using console.writeline that you can see in output window and check up to which point it prints messages. Especially put some messages in MeasurementsForm  Constructor and in the code which shows the form.

Comment: i suggest use some application level variables and simplify the code